# Is it possible to de-gloss paint?

Tags: finish, oil-based-paint

I have some satin black enamel paint, after applying it I found it to be too glossy. I know you can make paint more glossy, for example by adding varnish to it, but is there a way to make it less glossy?

Answer (score 6):

You can coat it with a satin clear finish. or even a matte finish. Both are available at most paint stores and big box stores.

Comment: But does a matte clear finish give glossy paint a matte look? Or will it simply not _add_ a glossy finish on top of it? I think I'll try it and see.

Comment: The matte on top of gloss will *de-gloss* it (as will satin). It might not be truly matte, but it should be significantly less shiny. I would wait a few days after the gloss is applied to ensure that it is fully dried. Also, on average, matte finishes are often less durable than other finishes, so if you can live with satin, that might give you better long term results.

Answer (score 5):

I had that same problem (oil based paint too glossy). 000 steel wool worked, sanding worked, tsp had no effect, vinegar had no effect.
 I mixed some talc (baby powder)  with my oil based high gloss paint and was able to get the flat appearance I wanted.  I found that it took a ratio of about 6 parts paint to 1 part talc to get the desired result

Answer (score 3):

Use steel wool or plastic abrasive pads on it (after it's dried.)

There are also "paint flattening agents" if you are looking for a chemical/additive fix for another coat.

Comment: Wouldn't this leave a 'scratched' finish? I want it to be smooth but not glossy.

Comment: If you use fine abrasives (0000 steel wool, white or gray "Scotchbrite", etc.) the "scratches" will be so fine they are not perceptible as "scratches."

Answer (score 3):

The 2 answers you have amount to (i) roughen it, and (ii) satin/matte varnish it.

I suggest doing *both*.  When you're applying one finish on top of another, neither of which is primer/undercoat, you need a good key -- hence roughening the surface.  You don't want to create visible scratches though. At some point you want to leave it in a warm place for a couple of days to make sure it's completely dry. Then wipe over with methylated spirits to remove dust/grease. Then you can apply your top coat.  Be sure to use a product with the same base as the paint you've just put on -- a water-based finish like acrylic varnish won't stick well to fresh oil paint.

You could of course -- if you're buying something anyway -- get a satin paint for a last coat.

Answer (score 3):

For the best possible results, just go buy the same paint in a less glossy firm and repaint the wall. All the other solutions will take as much time and still might not give the results you want. Save time and effort and just repaint.

Comment: Problem is, I couldn't find a less glossy paint. They did sell chalkboard paint, but I'm not sure if that's a good option.

Answer (score 2):

TSP has been used by painters for many years to "de-gloss" paint.
I have used it to both flatten a painted rooms glossy look, as well as to provide a surface that a new top coat can adhere to.
Gloss enamel needs to be cut (a surface tooth) established for new paint to adhere.  If you do not provide a tooth for new paint it can peel off of glossy enamel (a lesson learned for me long ago).

Answer (score 1):

Add a small amount of talc (try 2 TBSP per gallon). Try painting it on a small piece of wood to see how it looks. Add more or less depending on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Buy some zinc and add to your gloss finish enamel paint and mix it 
In this way you can make in matt enamel

Comment: Metallic zinc, zinc oxide, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Old trick given to me by old coach painter was add talc to the oil paint 
Soaks up the oil in the paint dulling it.

Be careful with what Making It Matt suggested. Don't add to much or it goes gritty rough.

Answer (score 0):

Rub glossy paint on dry wall with hand sanitizer (Walmart Equate brand) on a paper towel.  It will remove the gloss, super fast, super simple.  No sanding, no matte clear coat.  Just wipe.

Comment: Hand sanitizer is mostly alcohol, and alcohol dissolves latex paint, so I can see where this would remove some of the surface finish.  Does this work with enamel paint (as in the question)?

Answer (score 0):

For liquid paint that you want to dry with less gloss, add diatomaceous earth. Available as swimming pool filter supplies. Talc might work but I believe diatomaceous earth is used by paint manufacturers. You would need to experiment to find how much to get the affect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hand sanitizer seems to remove somesurface paint but did not remove gloss completely.

Comment: It's probably the alcohol, but I'd be worried about getting even results (i.e. not splotchy). Any suggestions on how to keep the results uniform?

Answer (score 0):

I used Soft Scrub, a very mild abrasive cleaner with small grit particles. Put a small amount on a clean white rag and abrade the glossy finish to your satisfaction.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the time its best with the proper grade of sandpaper/steelwool, to sand between coats or alternating coats. Experimentation is a great learning tool. At a mere cost of your time and some money.

Answer (score -2):

Just wipe it with vinegar. There will be no more gloss. Try in an inconspicuous spot first to see if you like the result before going any further.

Comment: Tried this, it did nothing.

Comment: If a painted surface can be modified just with vinegar, its not very good paint.  Might affect some types of lacquer or shellac.