# How to reduce the sheen of a wall paint?

Tags: walls, paint

I got the same color of existing wall color. But the problem is that even though the existing paint is at the least glossiness, it is still a lot more glossy than the old walls. Is there any paint or method I can use to reduce the glossiness of wall paint so I can match the old walls with the paint I got?

Edit:
To further the conversation. Is there any coating paint that will reduce the sheen gradually by the number of layers being applied. For example, when I apply first layer, it will dull the sheen for certain percentages, and then the second layer will dull the sheen for certain amount, until I can very closely match the surrounding color and sheen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to de-gloss paint?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/71996/is-it-possible-to-de-gloss-paint)

Comment: Google dead flat varnish  it may cost more than buying a gallon of flat paint of right color.   If you bought a sample matched to your color be aware that samples are usually only available in satin finish

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful information, I have edited my original question for further discussion.

Comment: Can you use something like Floetrol a thinning additive so that as you dilute the paint will decrease the gloss?

Comment: Paint the entire wall. If you can still actually notice it at the corner, that's not even close to the right paint.

Comment: The idea is to not paint the entire walls for small spots. The paint has the exact same color (as in certain angle, they are indistinguishable) but different sheen.

Answer (score 1):

No.   The paint doesn't have a glossy "finish", the gloss is built into the paint.   You must repaint.    Anything that "deglosses" your wall will certainly hurt the quality of your paint job and with 100% certainty will not match your other wall.

Comment: I agree with this answer and will add that it sounds like the OP (per comments) is trying to "touch up" areas but is using some other paint than the original, which is without a doubt **impossible** to get perfect. Paint the whole wall if you want to preserve your sanity.